# ssis package error while running locally and on server

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-agent-job

There was an error with Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Time] on Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Error: 0xC0209029 at Load_SB_Delinq_Loans, Excel Source [63]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Time]" failed because error code 0xC0209072 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Time]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Error: 0xC0047038 at Load_SB_Delinq_Loans, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more

I get the following error while running a package locally and through sql server agent job. The source is flat file .xlsxand destinationn is OLE DB and the sourceinput-output properties for time column data type is Date[DT_Date] and in the destination, the input-output properties for time column is UNICODE_String[DT_WSTR]. How do i solve the issue

I tried to run the ssis package both locally and through sql server agent job. The source is flat file .xlsxand destinationn is OLE DB and the sourceinput-output properties for time column data type is Date[DT_Date] and in the destination, the input-output properties for time column is UNICODE_String[DT_WSTR]. How do i solve the issue

Comment: Check the format of the date/time values in your source Time column. The formats yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss or dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss will successfully convert to DT_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a mismatch between the type/format of the source column and the destination column. You can try fixing it through Advanced Editor -> Input/Output columns, but sometimes that's clunky.

For now I would recommend setting both columns to String (possibly using Data Conversion) and see if that works.

Also, check your Excel Destination file whether the destination column has a different format than you expect. Making sure it's "General" should work.